# ArgumentException when adding UserControl to StackPanel

Tags: c#, silverlight

When a program is trying to add WordBlock (which is my class extending UserControl) to StackPanel's content in DoSend method, it sometimes (actually quite often, especially when query returns more than one result) throws an ArgumentException, it surely has something to do with Threading (SearchThreadEngine is a method running in in second thread), but I am weak in the topic, and don't know why it is happenig. So, I will gladly accept any help.
Here's a stack trace:

```
{System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddValue[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, CValue value)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_AddDependencyObject[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, DependencyObject value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.AddDependencyObject(DependencyObject value)
at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.Add(T value)
at Dictionary.MainPage.DoSend(IQueryable`1 words, WordContext context)} System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

```
public void DoSend(IQueryable<Word> words, WordContext context)
{
    Result.Children.Clear();
    using (context)
    {

        foreach (Word word in words)
        {
            Result.Children.Add(new WordBlock(word));
        }
        waitHandle.Set();
    }

}
public void SearchThreadEngine()
{
    while (!abort)
    {

        if (ToSearch != "")
        {
            string toSearch = ToSearch;
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            if (toSearch != ToSearch)
                continue;
            WordContext wc = new WordContext(WordContext.connectionString);
            ToSearch = "";
            IQueryable<Word> result = (from w in wc.Words where w.Foreign.Equals(toSearch) || w.Foreign.StartsWith(toSearch+" ") select w);
            if(result.Count() == 0)
                result = (from w in wc.Words where w.Foreign.Equals("to "+toSearch) || w.Foreign.StartsWith("to "+toSearch + " ") select w);
            if (result.Count() != 0)
            {
                Result.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SendResult(DoSend), new Object[] { result, wc });
                waitHandle.WaitOne();
            }

        }

    }
    abort = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Result.Children.Add(new WordBlock(word))
```

If the control has the `same name as another` this is the error you will receive. Each member must have a unique name.

Comment: Control name was "this" and when I removed Name="this" line from xaml part of control, everything started to work perfectly, but I do not quite understand why. Could you explain it?

Comment: They have to have unique names. Since you named each in `xaml` they all had the same names.